# flexbox elements too far apart with different font sizes

Tags: css

I need all of my elements inside my flexbox container to be close to each other. Unfortunately, since they have different font sizes, this is proving hard to accomplish. I could fix it using margins, but it seems like a hacky way to do it.

```css
#price {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#currency {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#price:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#price-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="price-info">
  <p id="currency">U$S</p><input id="price" type="text" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  <p>$/m2{sizePrice}</p>
</div>
```

[Updated problem, still spacing problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AeqL.png)

Comment: Try putting your elements (which you want on the same line) in same level say div and then wrap it around another div and apply flexbox on it.

Comment: I managed to get them on the same line by using margin: auto on all of the children, but they still seem far apart. See updated pic.

Comment: @David You can check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

```css
#price{
font-weight: bold;
border:none;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

#currency{
  color:#000000;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#price:focus {
  outline:none;
}

#price-info{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline
}
```

```html
<div id="price-info">
<p id="currency">U$S</p><input id="price" type="text" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<p>$/m2{sizePrice}</p>
</div>
```

Here is a possible solution you are looking for.

You can play around with `justify-content` to place your elements horizontally.
I believe what you wanted can be done by `align-items` property.

Comment: Doesn´t really work, the items still remain too far away

Comment: Do you mean horizontally ?

Comment: Particularly <p>$/m2{sizePrice}</p> remains way too far on the right

Comment: I am guessing it is due to some custom css applied on the `input` tag.

Comment: If you do inspect element from your browser, you will see the second `<p>` tag is right next to your `input`. It is the width of the input that is pushing your p tag that far.
Flexbox has correctly placed it right next to it without any additional space.

Try giving `input` a `width: 200px`, you will understand what I mean

Comment: Well if your component is of fixed size then you can just give a fixed width to your `input` tag. If has to be responsive i.e work on different resolutions then you will have to resort to media queries. Define a width (accordingly) for each resolution for your input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. but is not much easy you have to set margins manually

```css
#price {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#currency {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: .3rem;
}

#price:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#price-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#size-price{
  margin-left: -5rem;
}


.itens{
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="price-info">
  <p class="itens" id="currency">U$S</p>
  <input class="itens" id="price" type="text" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  <p class="itens" id="size-price">$/m2{sizePrice}</p>
</div>
```